# Best practice for `pallet_referenda::Curve`

Tags: governance, referenda

How do I configure these curves?

In general, when should I use `LinearDecreasing`, `SteppedDecreasing`, and `Reciprocal`?

What values should I choose for these arguments?

```rs
pub const fn make_linear(
    length: u128,
    period: u128,
    floor: FixedI64,
    ceil: FixedI64
) -> Curve

pub const fn make_reciprocal(
    delay: u128,
    period: u128,
    level: FixedI64,
    floor: FixedI64,
    ceil: FixedI64
) -> Curve
```

For example, I have seen `min_support: pallet_referenda::Curve::make_linear(14, 14, permill(5), percent(25))`.

Why not just write `pallet_referenda::Curve::make_linear(1, 1, permill(5), percent(25))`? What is the basis for using `14 / 14`?

And could you explain this real world example?

```rs
min_approval: pallet_referenda::Curve::make_reciprocal(
    1,
    14,
    percent(96),
    percent(50),
    percent(100),
),
```